# Cancel pending setTimeouts for multiple items in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a cool little micro interaction, but I'm running into a minor issue.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  const
    items = document.querySelector('nav').children
  if (items[0].getBoundingClientRect().top >= document.querySelector('nav').getBoundingClientRect().bottom){
    // start showing elements, starting from the left side
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
      setTimeout(function(){
        items[i].style.transform = 'translateY(0)'
      }, i * 200)
    }
  } else {
    // start hiding elements, starting from the right side
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
      setTimeout(function(){
        items[i].style.transform = 'translateY(100%)'
      }, (items.length-1 - i) * 200)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  width: 50vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: red;
}

nav > a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transition: .5s transform;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<nav>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
</nav>
```

If you toggle in too quick of a succession, some items will ultimately be displayed, whereas others will ultimately be hidden.

This is due to the fact that there are pending `setTimeouts` that have yet to be executed when the new set of `setTimeouts` are issued.

Obviously there are ways around this issue, like not reversing the order of the animation, waiting until the animation is completely finished before allowing the reverse, et cetera, but I would rather not make such compromises.

I've tried using and toggling a global Boolean in the `if` and `else` blocks, and then using an additional `if/else` statement in the `setTimeout` block, but this didn't work.

I also tried setting `transition` delays on the fly before applying the new `transform` values, instead of relying on `setTimeout`, which didn't work.

**Is there a** simple **way to cancel or ignore any pending `setTimeouts` from the** older **cycle?**

Comment: What is supposed to do? Click toggle button...nothing happens. Click one of the links and it goes nowhere of course.

Comment: @zer00ne not sure why its not working for u? works for me and im assuming worked for the other buddy who already provided an answer?

Comment: @zer00ne if for whatever reason u still cant get it to work, heres a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/details/gJgrYe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify your logic and consider `transition-delay` where you only need to toggle a class. The trick is to have a different delay for your elements when we toggle the class to have the desired effect.

With this configuration you won't have any issue because all the element will have the same state since the class is added to their parent element.

```js
var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  nav.classList.toggle('top');
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  width: 50vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: red;
  --d:0.2s;
}

nav > a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transition: .5s transform;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: lime;
}
nav.top > a {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

nav > a:nth-last-child(1) { transition-delay:calc(0 * var(--d));}
nav > a:nth-last-child(2) { transition-delay:calc(1 * var(--d));}
nav > a:nth-last-child(3) { transition-delay:calc(2 * var(--d));}  
nav > a:nth-last-child(4) { transition-delay:calc(3 * var(--d));}

nav.top > a:nth-child(1) { transition-delay:calc(0 * var(--d));}
nav.top > a:nth-child(2) { transition-delay:calc(1 * var(--d));}
nav.top > a:nth-child(3) { transition-delay:calc(2 * var(--d));}  
nav.top > a:nth-child(4) { transition-delay:calc(3 * var(--d));}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<nav>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
</nav>
```

We can simplify the CSS code by grouping the elements with the same delay:

```js
var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  nav.classList.toggle('top');
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  width: 50vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: red;
  --d:0.2s;
}

nav > a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transition: .5s transform;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: lime;
}
nav.top > a {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

nav > a:nth-last-child(1),
nav.top > a:nth-child(1) { transition-delay:calc(0 * var(--d));}

nav > a:nth-last-child(2),
nav.top > a:nth-child(2) { transition-delay:calc(1 * var(--d));}

nav > a:nth-last-child(3),
nav.top > a:nth-child(3){ transition-delay:calc(2 * var(--d));}  

nav > a:nth-last-child(4),
nav.top > a:nth-child(4){ transition-delay:calc(3 * var(--d));}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<nav>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: dude youre a fucking wizard. its funny cuz i just tried setting `transition-delays` before applying new `transform` values in JS, but i couldnt get it to work. i never thought my understanding of CSS was so bad until i started working on this project lol

Comment: i actually just figured it out using JS too. so instead of applying the style directly in the `setTimeout`, calling another function from and after the timeout and then applying whether a boolean is true or false does the trick too. but your answer/approach is so much more eloquent so ill be using yours :D

Comment: @Anthony yes better avoid JS as much as possible while you are at the early stage of a project. Keep JS for things that are really impossible with CSS.

Comment: @Anthony you can even be better ;) there is no magic, it's all about *hard* working

Comment: Good job!! This is so satisfying I can't stop clicking the button 

Comment: random question regarding something i was thinking about before. thought id ask you instead of posting a whole other question. is there any way to retrieve the index of an item in an HTML collection (i.e. ele.children)?

Comment: exactly like that but is there no way to do it in vanilla JS other than looping the the collection?

Comment: @Anthony no I don't think there is a vanilla JS for this. You may ask such question in the JS Chat Room to confirm this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif [any idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213803/bug-in-safari-ios-12-2-and-12-3?noredirect=1#comment99048688_56213803)

Comment: @Anthony no sorry, I have no way to test this behavior

Comment: @TemaniAfif any idea how to add a transition to the `height` of [this effect?](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/MdrZWL) ive tried using `flex` and `min-height`, but that didnt work either. i hate how you cant transition `height: auto`.

Comment: nm figured it out thx to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331169/7543162) can use `max-height` instead of `height`

Answer (score 0):

[This anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860203/10221765) shows a good way to clear all `setTimeout` - just add it into each part of the `if/else` statement:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
    const
      items = document.querySelector('nav').children

    if (items[0].getBoundingClientRect().top >= document.querySelector('nav').getBoundingClientRect().bottom) {
      var id = window.setTimeout(() => {}, 0);
      while (id--) {
        window.clearTimeout(id);
      }
      // start showing elements, starting from the beginning
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          items[i].style.transform = 'translateY(0)'
        }, i * 200)
      }
    } else {
      var id = window.setTimeout(() => {}, 0);
      while (id--) {
        window.clearTimeout(id);
      }
        // start hiding elements, starting from the back
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            items[i].style.transform = 'translateY(100%)'
          }, (items.length - 1 - i) * 200)
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  width: 50vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: red;
}

nav>a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transition: .5s transform;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<nav>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
  <a href=''></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: this method, although it successfully "cancels" the set of "forward/show" transitions, isnt working when one tries to "cancel" the set of "backwards/hide" transitions

Comment: does `var id...` basically state that "any `setTimeouts` that are set *in this block (?)* of code are identified as `id`"?

Comment: Mr. B, what exactly does this do? Click the toggle button -- nothing happens just like OP.

Comment: @zer00ne Click the toggle button twice in quick succession and the tiles reset.

Comment: @JackBashford they only reset if initially theyre hidden. however, if initially theyre visible, they dont reset, but pause for a second and then continue hiding themselves??