# Bug in Safari iOS 12.2 and 12.3

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

So I noticed something peculiar while working on a personal project just now.

The following code will cause an issue with the position of the `div` element in portrait mode if the phone is switched back and forth between orientations.

Instead of the `div` sitting fixed or flush to the bottom of the screen, the div will float above and not touch the bottom of the screen at all.

```css
  html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid blue 3px; box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid black 3px;
    background: white;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

While troubleshooting this issue, I discovered the following things:

- If you change the `height` of `html` from `100%` to `110%`, the issue resolves itself.
- `110%` is very likely not the exact "break" point, but I do know that the `div` will not touch the bottom of the screen even if the `height` of `html` is set to as much as `105%`.
- The dimensions of the square do not matter too much. I've tested at `10px`, `50px`, `100px`, and `200px`, and it disappears completely if set to `10px`, but behaves the way I've described above for all the other values.

Notably, I am testing this on, not an iPhone 6s, but a plain iPhone 6.

I encourage other users to test this for yourselves and share your experience!

**Does this bug exist on other devices? In other iOS versions?**

**Is there any way to fix this other than increasing the `height` of `html` to `110%`?**

Comment: Did you set the `margin` of `body` to `0`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge ya i did. `margin` has no effect. this is basically an MVP, aside from not knowing the **exact** "break" point